# How to install BLAS libraries on Anaconda 2.7

Tags: python, blas

I was running Python code for CIFAR-10 data using Convolutional Neural Network with Keras in Windows10, but got the error:

AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU, is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?

I have done some searching about the error and found I need to install BLAS.

Comment: Read the [theano-docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html) on how to prepare BLAS. This has nothing to do with Anaconda. It's a system-install.